# Почему токен возвращаемый ulogin невалидный?

Tags: php, ulogin

Делаю с сайта ulogin всё по интсрукции, авторизируюсь и получаю токен.
Потом я делаю запрос:

```
$vk = new VK\Client\VKApiClient('5.95');
try {
   $vk->users()->get($_POST['token'], []);
}
catch(VK\Exceptions\Api\VKApiAuthException $E) {
  echo $E->getMessage();
}
```

Пишет ошибку:

> User authorization failed: invalid access_token (4).

Раньше я делал обычную авторизацию со своим приложением и всё работало, поставил `ulogin` и теперь не понимаю что делать. У них на сайте написано что нужно зарегистрироваться, я зарегистрировался и указал секретный код приложения, но дальше они не пишут никаких инструкций как заставить всё это работать и чтобы я имел доступ к `api` и мог вывести информацию профиля

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/PHP_SDK   плюс посмотреть бы как вы auth_url формируете

Comment: access_token находится в $_GET, а не в $_POST